# Full disk enryption while installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, encryption, decryption

While installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I accidently checked the Full disk encryption box and entered the passphrase(known to me now) and then, didnt install the Ubuntu as partition system was not known to me. Now, from live CD of Ubuntu, I an see the following partitions.

/dev/sda1   ext2           487MiB   17.66MiB used

/dev/sda2   extended       465.28 GiB

/dev/sda5   crypt-luks     465.28 GiB

Please tell me how to recover the disk and I dont want to lose any data that is stored in the 465GB partition.

Comment: If installing then what data are you trying to save or recover?

Comment: STOP using system. Use overwrites more data. A lot of it is gone, that is why we always suggest full backups for any major system change. But Ubuntu writes across entire disk with full disk LVM install and is not large when first installed,  you You can try testdisk to see if its deeper search shows files. There are tools like photorec that scan system for files, but only find extension (file type) but not full name. Some Windows tools work better for NTFS partitions.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery & 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: Media more importantly. Documents and pics. Full disk if possible.

Comment: There is NO EASY WAY to recover your media. You cannot un-crack an egg. You are beyond the help that AskUbuntu can provide. @oldfred's advice is by far the best you will receive. You are about to learn a lot about the complicated and time-consuming world of data recovery.

Comment: I believe the Ubuntu installer writes random data to the partition as part of the configuration of the encryption. In that event there is no recovery. You can try testdisc and photorec to see if they can find any meaningful data